Spline interpolation with given inflection point
I am trying to get a function (cubic or higher degree, I think) to interpolate between $2$ points with horizontal tangents at ends and also a given inflection point at a given $x$ value ($x_i$). The constraints for $S(x)$ are ($S(x)$ being a $4$ degree equation):
$$\begin{align}
S(x_1) &=y_1 \\
S(x_2) &=y_2 \\
S'(x_1) &=0 \\
S'(x_2) &=0. \\
\end{align}$$
Now, for the inflection point at $x_i$ I've tried
$$S''(x_i)=0$$ and also
$$S''(x_{i1}) + S''(x_{i2})=0;$$
$x_{i1}$,$x_{i2}$ being values in the vicinity of $x_i$ (trying to set the values where the second derivative changes sign).
But this results in both overshooting and inflection point being shifted.
This is  for inflection points at $75$, $150$ and $225$ $(25\%,50\%,75\%)$ for both solutions alike.

The question is: Is this kind of interpolation even possible? Is there such a constraint that can be implemented to interpolate with a given inflection point $x$ value?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Yes, you can find a 4-th degree function whose endpoint tangents are the ones you want, and with an inflection at some other point (almost ... see below). But it's unlikely to be "pretty". Let's do it.
First, simplify: it's enough to solve the problem for $x_1 = -1, x_2 = 1, y1 = -1, y_2 = 1$. Why? Suppose that $y = g(x)$ solves that problem. Then
$$
k(x) = g(x-1) + 1
$$
solves the problem for $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 2, y_1 = 0, y_2 = 2$, which means that
$$
n(x) = \frac12 k(x/2)
$$
solves it for $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 1, y_1 = 0, y_2 = 1$. And then
by composing $n$ with a function of the form $x = (x-x_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$, you can shift your original problem to this domain; a similar thing can be done with $y$. So the problem is now:
Given a number $-1 < u < 1$, fund a quartic
$$
f(x) = ax^4  + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e
$$
with $f(-1) = -1; f(1) = 1$, $f'(-) = f'(1) = 0$, and $f''(u) = 0$.
Those are five linear conditions on a five-variable problem, so it should work out pretty well.
The first two conditions tell us that
\begin{align}
a - b + c - d + e &= -1 \\
a + b + c + d + e &= 1 
\end{align}
which, by adding and subtracting the two equations, we can reduce to
\begin{align}
a     + c     + e &= 0 \\
 b +  d  &= 1 
\end{align}
The conditions on the derivatives tell us that
\begin{align}
-4a + 3b - 2 c + d &= 0\\
 4a + 3b + 2 c + d &= 0
\end{align}
which (adding and subtracting again) give us
\begin{align}
2a + c  &= 0\\
3b + 2 d &= 0
\end{align}
(We still haven't gotten to the inflection, but we will!)
From $b + d = 1$ and $3b + 2d = 0$, we get $b = \frac12$ and $d = \frac32$, so finally, something concrete.
From the other two equations, we get
$$
a = -e\\
c = -2e
$$
So we're down to just the one unknown, $e$. This is where the inflection point information comes in. The condition $f''(u) = 0$ becomes
$$
12au^2 + 6b u + 2c = 0
$$, and substituting in what we know about $a, b,$ and $c$ makes this
$$
12eu^2 + (6 \cdot -\frac12) u + 2(-2e) = 0
$$
i.e.,
$$
12eu^2 -3u -4e = 0
$$
Factoring out the $e$ and moving $3u$ to the other side, we have
$$
e(12u^2 - 4) = 3u
$$
so that
$$
e = \frac{3u}{12u^2- 4} =  \frac{3u}{4(3u^2 - 1)}.
$$
You can use a tool like Desmos to plot the results:

And they look pretty nice. (I've used "w" instead of "e" here because Desmos wants to treat $e$ as $2.71828...$)
The problem is that as you adjust $u$ towards $-1$ or $1$, the plot goes way above or below $y = \pm 1$. And the even deeper problem comes when you pick $u = \pm \sqrt{3}$, because that makes the formula for $e$ become
$$
e = \frac{3u}{4(3(\sqrt{3}^2 - 1)} = \frac{3u}{4 \cdot 0}.
$$
So for those two conditions, there's actually no quartic polynomial that has the property that you wanted. And even without this, if you plug in $u = -0.5$, you see that the endpoint conditions are satisfied, and that $f''(-0.5) = 0$, but there's another inflection point around $x = 0.9$. There's no reason there shouldn't be --- the equations we specified put no conditions on this --- but we were hoping for better.
That's it. Life's sometimes disappointing. You can fit a quartic that does what you asked (except for two exceptional cases), but it turns out that it doesn't have other properties that you were hoping for (but didn't specify).
If you instead insist that $f''(x) > 0$ for $x < u$ and $f''(x) < 0$ for $x > u$, then you get a problem with no solution in general.
There's another question worth asking: do you really care about polynomials? If not, there are other functions that can do a lot of what you're asking.

Thank you very much for your answer, it really helped me to make up my mind on this approach.
I wasn't aware that there are other ways to do this as my math skills are not that good.
So, if you had the time to help me get on the right track, I would very much appreciate.
Thank you once again.
